# Keyboard shortcut to show Tags... dialog

Tags: finder, applescript, mojave

In the Finder, you can select a file and choose Tags... from the File menu or contextual menu. It will show a little dialog that allows you to select or type tag names, and you can press Enter to apply them to the selected file.

[image]

Before Mac OS Mojave, I was able to assign a keyboard shortcut to this menu item (using a method [like this](http://osxdaily.com/2014/03/10/tag-files-keyboard-shortcut-mac-os-x/), although I'm using Keyboard Maestro).

But with Mojave, Tags... is no longer a standard menu item, so it can't be accessed this way. Using an ellipsis character instead of three periods doesn't help. Is there a way to do this now? I tried scripting System Events, but couldn't get it working.

Comment: _"It's not the ellipsis vs periods issue"_  If you post your code, someone might be able to discern what the issue is and fix it for you.

Comment: I don't have any code to post....I was referring to the difference between three periods and an ellipsis character, which can sometimes make it difficult to find menu items via code. I'll clarify.

Comment: You said in your post explicitly _"I tried scripting System Events, but couldn’t get it working."_

Answer (score 1):

This no longer seems possible with Mac OS 10.14. My workaround has been to use Keyboard Maestro, with the following macro:

```
For Each Item in the Collection Execute Actions
    For Each FilePath in the Finder selection
Execute the Following Actions:
    Get Tags to Variable ‘Tags’
    From file: %Variable%FilePath%

Prompt for User Input ‘Tags’
    Prompt: Enter tag to toggle
Input the following variables:
    Tags (default to ‘%Variable%Tags%’)
Finish with the following buttons:
    OK
    Cancel (cancel macro)

For Each Item in the Collection Execute Actions
    For Each FilePath in the Finder selection
Execute the Following Actions:
    Set Tags to ‘%Variable%Tags%’
    File: %Variable%FilePath%
```

If you select some Finder items and run this macro, it will prompt you to enter tags. You can enter multiple tags separated by commas. Pressing OK will apply those tags to the selected items. The prompt will be pre-filled with the tags of the last item in the selection (this part of the macro isn't ideal).